# How do I get the index of an object in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

I try to fetch some data from my database and show it in a chart but I have problems to display it correctly. I want the x-value to be the index of the fetched data.

```
async function getBatteryset() {
    let url = '/getBatLevel.php';
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
async function renderBattData() {
    let dataset = await getBatteryset();
    let html = '<figure class="css-chart" style="--widget-size:650px;"><ul class="line-chart">';
    dataset.forEach(data => {
        let htmlSegment = `<li>
                            <div class="data-point" data-value=${data.ID} style="bottom: ${data.BatV*100}px; left: ${data}px"></div>
                        </li>`;

        html += htmlSegment;
    });
    html += '</ul></figure>'
    let container = document.querySelector('.BattChart');
    container.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working ? What errors have you encountered ? What have you tried so far to solve the problem, if any ?

Comment: First of all I tried to solve this in the database by adjusting the coresponding field. That way I won't need the index. That did not work and when I searched it it says that in my case data should be already the index I need

Comment: If you want to get the index of the current element in a `forEach` you just need to use the second parameter in the callback function.

Comment: Your code sample has a lot of extraneous detail. Where is the "x-value" you mention in your code sample? Is it the `left` property within `htmlSegment`?

Comment: yes you are correct, I'm sorry. It is the left property.

Comment: `dataset.forEach((data, index) => {`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this:

```js
dataset.forEach((data, i) => {

    const offset = 100 // choose an offset here for each element on the X axis
    
    let htmlSegment = 
        `<li>
            <div class="data-point" data-value=${data.ID} style="bottom: ${data.BatV*100}px; left: ${i * offset}px"></div>
        </li>`;

    html += htmlSegment;
});
```

Also please note that your code is potentially vulnerable to DOM based XSS if the data comes from a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use map. Both map and forEach have the index as second parameter

```js
let html = `<figure class="css-chart" style="--widget-size:650px;"><ul class="line-chart">
    $(dataset.map((data,i) => `<li>
      <div class="data-point" data-value=${data.ID} style="bottom: ${data.BatV*100}px; left: ${i * offset}px"></div>
    </li>`).join("")}
  </ul></figure>`;
```